# Is it possible to relate two types together?

Tags: c#

This is a thought exercise. I don't need help simplifying this code or to accomplish the same thing without relating the types. The code is convoluted because it attempts to identify a pattern that could be used if alternatives were not available.

The idea is to see if one can create arbitrary relationships between various types that is enforced by the compiler.

I want to be able create a set of types `{T1, T2, T3, T4, ...}` that are related to another set of types `{Ta, Tb, Tc, Td, ... }` in the same way. Once the relationship is established, I want to be able to use a type in the second set, by only using the related type in the first set. For example, if a function is given type T5, it should be able to create an instance of Te because T5 and Te are related.

In the example below, I'm using the types `{Nail, Screw}` and I want to relate them to their makers `{NailMaker, ScrewMaker}`. One constraint of this thought exercise is to use the **type** Nail to create a NailMaker, and not an **instance** of Nail to do so.

The objective is to be able to call a static member of a base class `Maker` with a type in the first set, to make an instance of the related type in the second set:

```
var factory = Maker<Nail>.Get()
```

Here `factory` would be an instance of `NailMaker` derived from `Maker<Nail>`, and `Get()` is a static function.

I need to somehow relate `NailMaker` to `Nail` but I haven't found a way to do that.

Something like:

```
static public Maker<T> Get()
{
   return T.GetMaker();
}
```

I have tried this and it works:

```
public abstract class Maker<T>
{

    static public Maker<T> Get<T2>() where T2: Maker<T>, new()
    {
        return new T2();
    }
}
```

However, I'd like it to work without passing T2.

Comment: Don't make it static.  Instantiate an instance of your factory.  Having it static defeats the testability of using a factory

Comment: I don't have an instance of a nail, before I create the nailmaker.

Comment: Why would you need one to create an instance of the factory?

Comment: Could you write an answer? I'm having a hard time following your comments.

Comment: You want to pass Nail to Maker to Give you NailMaker to create Nail ? Is that correct ?

Comment: That is correct @HanyHabib

Comment: You understand that using the generic `Maker<Nail>` doesn't require you to have an instance of `Nail`, right?

Comment: didn't you mean`public static Maker<T> Get<T>(){ return T.GetMaker(); }` instead ?

Comment: `T.GetMaker();` doesn't compile @Franck

Comment: @Amy yes, however your suggestion to not using a static method doesn't work when you don't have an instance of the class.

Comment: Then *instantiate* it.  Your design isn't making any sense at all.

Comment: @mustafa Ozturk .. it will not compile you need to cast it first to the base interface to be able to call GetMaker

Comment: Obviously but i was referring to the way it was written only. You need to set the type of `T` to the generic class that `Nail` and `Screw` are derived from then you can call the method

Comment: @HanyHabib I don't have an instance of the object to cast, I only have a type.

Comment: Use Activator.CreateInstance it creates instance by type

Comment: I updated my example to show what I have right now that works that I would like to improve. Perhaps it will help better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `however, I'd like it to work without passing T2.`  You can't.  The method can't return type `T` if it isn't provided.  Generics don't work based on the return type.

Comment: @Amy it is provided T which I hope to relate to T2, so I can return T2 when I have T. That is my goal and the purpose for this question.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk You *still* can't.  And no, you aren't providing `T` in your latest code.  It's in the return type, it isn't part of the method signature.

Comment: @Amy `static public Maker<T> Get<T2>() where T2: Maker<T>, new()` contains both `T` and `T2`

Comment: @MustafaOzturk It isn't part of the method signature.  It's in the result type.  You are not providing it.  I cannot say this any more clearly.  You *cannot* vary the return type unless the type is passed into the method somehow.

Comment: @Amy the method is in a generic class that is passed `T` and is called as follows `var factory = Maker<Nail>.Get<NailMaker>();`. I also expanded the text I included with my question, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the whole answer as this is much cleaner and closer to what you need.

First the `Maker` class (your `T2`). You would add the generic properties and methods your need :

```
public class Maker 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } = ""; 
}
```

Then the `Part` parent class that describe the parts and contain the matching `Maker` class

```
public class Part<T> where T : Maker 
{ 
    public static Type MakerType { get { return typeof(T); } } 
}
```

Then you need 1 `Maker` to match each `Part` so you create those :

```
public class NailMaker : Maker { public NailMaker() { Name = "Nail"; } }

public class ScrewMaker : Maker { public ScrewMaker() { Name = "Screw"; } }
```

Then we need the `Part` for each and with the `T2` / `Maker` class they are referring too.

```
public class Nail : Part<NailMaker> { }

public class Screw : Part<ScrewMaker> { }
```

Then getting the `Maker` class only required instantiation of the `Type` lying in the `Part` class that is `Static` hence no need to instantiate the `Part` class

```
var nailMaker = Activator.CreateInstance(Nail.MakerType);    
var screwMaker = Activator.CreateInstance(Screw.MakerType);
```

Comment: That would only be possible if C# would allow `virtual` or `abstract` method to be static which is not possible in the language. If it would be then that would complicate things on the how to get it as `T` is not known at the time you access the static

Comment: @MustafaOzturk i have modified a couple things to make is as close as possible to get the `T2` without instantiating the `Part` class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you will apply the usage of it, but refering to [Factory pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) you can implement something like this:

```
abstract class Maker {
   public abstract int SomeProperty { get; }
}

abstract class MakerFactory {
   public abstract Maker GetMaker();
}


class Nail:Maker {

}

class ConcreteNailFactory:NailFactory {
   public override Maker GetMaker() {
      return new Nail();
   }
}
```